# file:collection-2--7314949537073882860.wt could not be found in mongodb/log

Tags: mongodb

I am not able to start the mongo DB server. Process of starting is stopped and in the log files theres the following text:

```
2018-01-13T15:06:30.468+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=9372 port=27017 dbpath=C:\Jimmy\mongodb\db 64-bit host=LAPTOP-3Q22V2TI
2018-01-13T15:06:30.468+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] targetMinOS: Windows 7/Windows Server 2008 R2
2018-01-13T15:06:30.469+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.5.13
2018-01-13T15:06:30.469+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 52bbaa007cd84631d6da811d9a05b59f2dfad4f3
2018-01-13T15:06:30.469+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1u-fips  22 Sep 2016
2018-01-13T15:06:30.469+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2018-01-13T15:06:30.469+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2018-01-13T15:06:30.475+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2018-01-13T15:06:30.475+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: 2008plus-ssl
2018-01-13T15:06:30.475+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2018-01-13T15:06:30.475+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2018-01-13T15:06:30.476+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { config: "C:/Jimmy/mongodb/config.yml", net: { bindIp: "127.0.0.1", maxIncomingConnections: 10, ssl: { PEMKeyFile: "C:\Jimmy\mongodb\mongodb.pem", disabledProtocols: "TLS1_0,TLS1_1", mode: "requireSSL" } }, security: { authorization: "enabled" }, storage: { dbPath: "C:\Jimmy\mongodb\db", journal: { enabled: false }, mmapv1: { nsSize: 8 }, wiredTiger: { engineConfig: { cacheSizeGB: 1.0 } } }, systemLog: { destination: "file", path: "C:\Jimmy\mongodb\log\mongod.log" } }
2018-01-13T15:06:30.485+0100 I -        [initandlisten] Detected data files in C:\Jimmy\mongodb\db created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'wiredTiger'.
2018-01-13T15:06:30.485+0100 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=1024M,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),statistics_log=(wait=0),verbose=(recovery_progress),,log=(enabled=false),
2018-01-13T15:06:30.622+0100 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (2) [1515852390:622260][9372:140724104147712], file:collection-2--7314949537073882860.wt, WT_SESSION.open_cursor: C:\Jimmy\mongodb\db\collection-2--7314949537073882860.wt: handle-open: CreateFileW: Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden.
: No such file or directory
2018-01-13T15:06:30.622+0100 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] no cursor for uri: table:collection-2--7314949537073882860
2018-01-13T15:06:30.622+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] *** unhandled exception (access violation) at 0x00007FF672D7F535, terminating
2018-01-13T15:06:30.622+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] *** access violation was a read from 0x0000000000000058
```

Other research has not brought any results. How can I get/create the missing file?